# How to open List View from On Click Item?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, list, view

Good day,

Thanks to some users here, I was able to come up with code to open Context Menus from an item click. Now, I want one of my six items to open a List View. How can I implement a List View? I have used custom code from this source:

http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=146145

or

http://code.google.com/p/android-carousel-demo/source/browse/#svn%2FCarouselDemo%253Fstate%253Dclosed

I posted both links in case you prefer one or the other. I want one of the items in my carousel to open a List View. Can you help me with this? This is the code I am currently using. Thank you in advance.

```
package com.carouseldemo.main;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.carouseldemo.controls.Carousel;
import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselAdapter;
import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselAdapter.AdapterContextMenuInfo;
import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselAdapter.OnItemClickListener;
import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselAdapter.OnItemSelectedListener;
import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselItem;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    // Just prepare ourself for unexpected arguments...
    if (menuInfo == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (!(menuInfo instanceof AdapterContextMenuInfo)) {
        return;
    }
    AdapterContextMenuInfo mi = (AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;
    switch (mi.position) {
    case 0:
        menu.add("cat menu");
        break;
    case 1:
        menu.add("hippopotamus menu");
        break;
    case 2:
        menu.add("monkey menu");
        break;
    case 3:
        menu.add("mouse menu");
        break;
    case 4:
        menu.add("panda menu");
        break;
    case 5:
        menu.add("rabbit menu");
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
}


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final Carousel carousel = (Carousel)findViewById(R.id.carousel);
    carousel.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

                    public void onItemClick(CarouselAdapter<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                        CarouselItem item = (CarouselItem)parent.getChildAt(position);

                        // HERE: Force context menu
                        carousel.showContextMenuForChild(item);

                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                            String.format("%s has been clicked",
                                            item.getName()),
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

    });

    carousel.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

                    public void onItemSelected(CarouselAdapter<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                    final TextView txt = (TextView)(findViewById(R.id.selected_item));

                            switch(position){
                            case 0:
                                    txt.setText("The cat (Felis catus), also known as the domestic cat or housecat to distinguish it from other felids and felines, is a small, usually furry, domesticated, carnivorous mammal that is valued by humans for its companionship and for its ability to hunt vermin and household pests. Cats have been associated with humans for at least 9,500 years, and are currently the most popular pet in the world. Owing to their close association with humans, cats are now found almost everywhere in the world.");
                                    break;
                            case 1:
                                    txt.setText("The hippopotamus (Hippopotamus amphibius), or hippo, from the ancient Greek for \"river horse\" (ἱπποπόταμος), is a large, mostly herbivorous mammal in sub-Saharan Africa, and one of only two extant species in the family Hippopotamidae (the other is the Pygmy Hippopotamus.) After the elephant, the hippopotamus is the third largest land mammal and the heaviest extant artiodactyl.");
                                    break;
                            case 2:
                                    txt.setText("A monkey is a primate, either an Old World monkey or a New World monkey. There are about 260 known living species of monkey. Many are arboreal, although there are species that live primarily on the ground, such as baboons. Monkeys are generally considered to be intelligent. Unlike apes, monkeys usually have tails. Tailless monkeys may be called \"apes\", incorrectly according to modern usage; thus the tailless Barbary macaque is called the \"Barbary ape\".");
                                    break;
                            case 3:
                                    txt.setText("A mouse (plural: mice) is a small mammal belonging to the order of rodents. The best known mouse species is the common house mouse (Mus musculus). It is also a popular pet. In some places, certain kinds of field mice are also common. This rodent is eaten by large birds such as hawks and eagles. They are known to invade homes for food and occasionally shelter.");
                                    break;
                            case 4:
                                    txt.setText("The giant panda, or panda (Ailuropoda melanoleuca, literally meaning \"black and white cat-foot\") is a bear native to central-western and south western China.[4] It is easily recognized by its large, distinctive black patches around the eyes, over the ears, and across its round body. Though it belongs to the order Carnivora, the panda's diet is 99% bamboo.");
                                    break;
                            case 5:
                                    txt.setText("Rabbits (or, colloquially, bunnies) are small mammals in the family Leporidae of the order Lagomorpha, found in several parts of the world. There are eight different genera in the family classified as rabbits, including the European rabbit (Oryctolagus cuniculus), cottontail rabbits (genus Sylvilagus; 13 species), and the Amami rabbit (Pentalagus furnessi, an endangered species on Amami Ōshima, Japan)");
                                    break;
                            }

                    }

                    public void onNothingSelected(CarouselAdapter<?> parent) {
                    }

    }
    );

    registerForContextMenu(carousel);
}

}
```

Comment: What exactly is the question? What is/isn't working? Have you tried creating an `Activity` with a `ListView` and call that after clicking an item?

Comment: what is wrong with your code, what is the trouble you are having implementing it yourself, have you tried to implement it?

Comment: Yes, I do not know how to implement it with my custom items. I am a beginner. Any advice on how to perform this task would be good.

Answer (score 2):

I think It will be use this code

```
@Override  
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
 setContentView(R.layout.main);  

 listGames = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewGame);  
 gamelistArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.gameslist);  
 gameDetailsListArray = getResources().getStringArray(  
 R.array.gamesDetails);  

 adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,  
  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,  
 gamelistArray);  

 listGames.setAdapter(adapter);  

 listGames.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {  

  @Override  
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,  
 int position, long id) {  

// Get the item that was clicked  
Object itemName = listGames.getItemAtPosition(position);  
String keyword = itemName.toString();  
String info = gameDetailsListArray[position];  
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  
"You have selected:  " + keyword, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)  
  .show();  
Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(),  
  ActivityGameDetails.class);  
i.putExtra("info", info);  
i.putExtra("name", keyword);  
startActivity(i);  

}  
});  
}  
}
```

Check this one also

[ListView in Android (Advance)](http://www.rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2012/07/listview-in-android-advance.html)

ListView: ListView is a view group that displays a list of scrollable items.

[ListView in Android (Basic)](http://www.rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2011/08/list-view-in-android-basic.html)